# How can i make the inner LinearLayout stay under the last button when i rotate device to horizontal?

Tags: android, android-layout

Well the title speaks for it self. I suspect it has to do with the `ScrollView` but cannot figure this out. I want the LinearLayout content to stay aligned to the bottom.

[image]
[image]

Her's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollViewActivityLogin"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_top_activity_login"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_head_activity_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dip"            
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:text="@string/string_your_not_logged_on"
            android:textSize="22sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_username_activity_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_head_activity_login"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:text="@string/string_user_name"
             />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_username_activity_login"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_username_activity_login"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="text"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_password_activity_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edt_username_activity_login"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/string_password"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_password_activity_login"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_password_activity_login"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login_activity_login"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edt_password_activity_login"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:text="@string/string_login" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_sign_up_activity_login"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_login_activity_login"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
            android:text="@string/string_sign_up" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout_bottom_activity_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            >                  
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_version_activity_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_copywrite_activity_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/string_app_name_copywrite" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why dont you use separate layout for landscape mode ?

Comment: I know but wanted to keep it simple focusing on bigger issues at this point in BETA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change at top of the file like this.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollViewActivityLogin"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_top_activity_login"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

see this Image you will get more idea

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOai7.jpg

Comment: yes your right. Sorry Forgot to to say that i wanted the LinearLayout to be alignParentBottom. Updating question

Comment: Testing on device API V4 and it's not right same problem and now also half screen is black in landscape

Comment: make a new folder in "res" with name "layout-land" and make another xml file in it with same name of this and designed it as per land-scape mode.